# how to get the next day date in informaitca

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a date field coming form source paid_date and i want it to convert as
trunc(next_day(sysdate-1,'MON')).. I need to get the  NEXT_DAY here and the filed data type is date-time.
  Please share your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of now, there is no NEXT_DAY equivalent in Informatica. So you have to calculate it like this in expression.

```
TRUNC(
  ADD_TO_DATE(
    SYSDATE,
    'DD',
    (9 - TO_FLOAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D')))%7
  )
)
```

Explanation:

`(9 - TO_FLOAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D')))%7` - Calculates the number of days till next Monday.

`ADD_TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD',...)` - Adds the above no. of days to the input date

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use **Add_To_Date** function. Using this function you can get your exact date or month or year.

Formats of defining date,
Date – DD, DDD, DY and DAY
Month – MM, MON and MONTH
Year – YY, YYY and YYYY
Hour – HH, HH12 and HH24
Minute – MI
Seconds - SS

Syntax : ADD_TO_DATE (date_column, format, value)

Example: ADD_TO_DATE (Date, ‘DD’, 10)
Result:

```
10/01/2016  -  20/01/2016
```

As the format is provided as ‘DD’ and value as 10, the dates are displayed by increasing 10 days. This logics stands for date, month, year, minute, hour or seconds whatever defined in the syntax. To decrease the date value just add negative number (-10).

For you to get next day, just define 
    ADD_TO_DATE (Your column, ‘DD’, 1).

For more details on informatica just visit my blog,
http://etlinfromatica.wordpress.com/